# VB.NET Windows Service Main Code

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I am trying to learn how a Windows Service works using vb.net and I have no clue where to put my main code. what I mean by main code is the code that needs to be run every couple of seconds. So far, I was able to write a text file using onStart method provided by the service its self. I have installed the service manually and made it run.

do i need to create some kind of threading that trigger the main code? and in which method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Timer. They start an event on every tick. The tick can be modified to the length you want it to be.(Interval)

Here's a great article/tutorial on them: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/58033-using-timer/

Add a timer to your application by going to the toolbox and clicking a **Timer** and adding it to the form. Then go to the properties and add what interval you would like it to do an event(in milliseconds) the set the **enabled** property to **true**.

Click on the timer icon below the form designer and you will be directed to the code editor with the Timer_Tick event. Then in when I put the comment 'what you want it to do, this is the code that will be executed every tick(the interval what you selected, for example 1000 is a second)

Code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'what you want it to do
End Sub
```

If I am being unclear here is a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wWZIuOAyM4